# Share an Eclipse CDT project

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-cdt

I have been working on an embedded project with a friend and I like to send him the project every once in a while so he can go over the code.

What is the best way to send him the project so that he can build it fairly easily on his side.

Zipping up the workspace and sending it over does not seem to work very well and exporting the project and having him import it into a workspace doesn't seem to do what I want either.

**Update**

Thanks everyone for your input, I figured out how to install Subclipse and how to use it with my SVN repo. In order to allow my friend to do the same I went through and documented the installation of Subclipse as well as how to add-to and import-from the repository.

You can find it on my [blog](http://curiouslynerdy.com/2009/11/subclipse-svn-on-eclipse-cdt/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say go with a Source Code Repository (e.g. SVN).  There are many free options: gitHub, GoogleCode, Assembla etc.

I would discourage zipping & sending: you'll have trouble synchronizing the project and you will probably loose time.

Comment: I do have a SVN repo, I'm just not familiar enough with Eclipse to know how to get my project added. Does eclipse have native support SVN and git or is there a plugin that you'd recommend?

Comment: I use the Subclipse plugin for SVN: works well enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

Many people use Source Control systems such as SVN, Git, etc. Zipping workspaces is a very difficult way to keep in sync, especially if you continue to work on the project after you have sent it off.

If it is an Open Source project then there are several sites that host SVN or Git. Otherwise it will still be worth the effort of setting up a server.